# Async/await not working inside map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await, promise

I am looping over an array and based on the value fetching data from postgres via sequelize and then pushing that data to investment array.

However, the data is not inserted into the array orderly and after using console logs I found out that the sqlQuery is taking some time to fetch the data but the loop ends before that or is what I think it's happening.

```
    
    await Promise.all(array1.map(async (value) => {
        const sqlQuery = `sql query goes here`;
        console.log("test")

        const data = await sequelize.query(sqlQuery);
        const sqlData= data[0][0]

        investment.push(sqlData.amount);
        console.log("investment",investment);
    }));
```

The length of the "array1" is 4 and the when I run this block of code I receive this as the output

```
test
test
test
test
investment 2000
investment 4000
investment 1500
investment 2200
```

Ideally it should have been

```
investment 1500
investment 2000
investment 2200
investment 4000
```

What am I doing wrong here can someone please help me?

Comment: The callback function doesn't return anything, what are you expecting `Promise.all()` to return?

Comment: You run your queries in parallel (they execute in semi-random order). Promise.all() does nothing relevant here. Just do a standard loop with await.

Comment: I have been using Promise.all() so that the next piece of code after this map functions waits for the complete execution of this iteration. Have I been doing it wrong?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the queries will finish in the order that they were issued to the database server. You launch them all at basically the same time, and then they finish when they finish.

Comment: @freakish yes, exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL queries are being executed asynchronously, so they can complete in any order, and that's the order that the `investment.push()` calls happen.

You need to return the values from the callback functions, then `Promise.all()` will return them as an array in the same order as the promise array. This can then be assigned to `investment`.

```js
let investment =
  await Promise.all(array1.map(async(value) => {
    const sqlQuery = `sql query goes here`;
    console.log("test")

    const data = await sequelize.query(sqlQuery);
    const sqlData = data[0][0]

    return sqlData.amount;
  }));
```